# Button Shapes ON and SwiftUI TabView UI strange

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview

I made very simple `TabView` on `SwiftUI` and turn `Button Shapes` to `ON` and see a strange UI. You can see 3 rectangles at top of `Navigation View`. I don't know where's it come from.

Anybody can help?

#### 1. Button shapes ON

[image]

#### 2. UI strange

[image]

This is a sample code

```
TabView {
    ProfileView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "account")
            Text("Profile")
        }

    ...
}
```

With Navigation View

```
NavigationView {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.bottom, 30)
    }
    .navigationTitle("account".localized())
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Comment: Show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
that is simple but fully replicates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rectangles appeared when you toggled "Button Shapes" on, then there must be buttons there you didn't know about.

(I would have put this in a comment, but I don't have that privilege as of yet.)

Comment: You are right. I have some NavigationLinks with EmptyView() and it's some hidden buttons